# Deployed service in google cloud run cannot add new data

Tags: database, sqlite, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm learning how to deploy a simple notes website in google cloud run. In my deployed website, the users cannot sign up, delete notes, or add new notes. Old users can sign in and view their old notes. However, this is all possible in my local server. I am using SQlite for reference.

I tried to set the environment variable DATABASE_URI to the SQLite connection URI in my Cloud Run service configuration. So I did something like `--update-env-vars DATABASE_URI="sqlite:///[DB_NAME]"`. It did not work. I'm not sure why and how to fix this. I think it has to do with my database since it locally works. I did hear that google cloud run doesn't like sqlite but is there any way around that?

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), 'database.db')



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hjshjhdjah kjshkjdhjs'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI',f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}')
    db.init_app(app)
```

Comment: Is your database in memory?